# Center a container ul/div in a fluid layout

Tags: html, layout, css

I want to center a container div in a fluid lay-out (content with id: articles_grid has to be centered):
http://www.benskesblog.com/projects/frontend/project/index.htm

I've tried a lot a methods, but no one did work. (for example: margin: 0 auto;).

Could someone tell me how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe changes are pretty simple to achieve what you need:

```
#articles_grid {
...
text-align: center; /*add this*/
}

#articles_grid li {
...
/* float:left; remove this */
display: inline-block; /*add this*/
}
```

Comment: Oke i've marked it as correct (I didn't knew this option honestly)!  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can give `display:inline-block` to you `DIV` which you want in center & define text-align:center in his `parent DIV`. For example you can do like this:

**CSS:**

```
.parent{
    background:red;
    text-align:center;
}
.center{
    text-align:left;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;/* IE7 */
    *zoom:1;
    background:yellow;
    min-height:100px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="center">lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Check the example below:

### http://jsfiddle.net/aNR3a/

Comment: Thanks Sandeep! 
But is it also possible to center the list items in this yellow container? Like: http://jsfiddle.net/aNR3a/23/ (and images centered in yellow container)

Comment: @BangBang; did the same thing with your li also like this http://jsfiddle.net/aNR3a/43/  or if your li have fixed width then give margin: 0 auto;

Comment: Thanks for the help! Inline-block is very useful. I've been searching a lot, but I was searching in the wrong direction! :)